# Disable auto date formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

My cells are set to text format but when I find and replace numbers in them they automatically change themselves to date format even though I don't want that. How do I globally disable automatic formatting in Excel?

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible.  I would use VBA.  You could use the `.Find` method to locate cells containing the number to be replaced;  then use the `Replace` function to change the string in the cell, and write the results back to the cell.

Comment: :/ That's what I was afraid of. For now I'll just copy the cells into notepad.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for this would be to put an apostrophe (') in front of your "Replace with:" value.  Just one more keystroke.

[image: Find and Replace with leading apostrophe to keep text]

BTW:  Microsoft indicates that in **Excel 2013**, using the TEXT format will stop it from auto-converting numbers to dates.  [support.office.com: Stop automatically changing numbers to dates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8)

Comment: Thanks, it works. `using the **TEXT** format will stop it from auto-converting numbers to dates`